# Copying data for like values

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have a spreadsheet which contains invoice numbers and detail numbers. The detail numbers point to the line on the invoice where the information resides.  There can be multiple invoices on one spreadsheet, however and unfortunately, only one invoice and detail combination goes on a single line. So row 1 on my spreadsheet will contain a single invoice in column A and a detail in column B, then the next invoice starts on row 2. My problem is I want to create a program that will find any duplicate invoices and copy and paste the associated detail numbers to a single line so that I will end up with:

```
InvoiceA. Detail1. Detail2. Detail3. Etc
InvoiceB. Detail1. Detail2. Etc
```

As opposed to:

```
InvoiceA. Detail
InvoiceA. Detail
InvoiceB. Detail
InvoiceB. Detail
```

I have thought of going through each cell using a macro with advanced filters by invoice - count the visible rows and copy the details into the designated spots on the spreadsheet, then delete out the extra invoice numbers with only one detail number. However, this seems inefficient.

Here's what I cam up with so far

```
Sub detail()
   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
   Dim dtl1 As Range, dtl2 As Range, dtl3 As Range, dtl4 As Range, dtl5 As Range, dtl6 As Range

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
   lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set inv = ws.Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
   Set dtl1 = ws.Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
  '
  'ws.Range("E:I").EntireColumn.Insert
  'With ws
     '.Range("E1").Value = "Detail 2"
     '.Range("F1").Value = "Detail 3"
     '.Range("G1").Value = "Detail 4"
     '.Range("H1").Value = "Detail 5"
     '.Range("I1").Value = "Detail 6"
  'End With

   For i = 1 To ws.Rows.Count
      If inv.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
         Exit Sub
      End If
      If inv.Cells(i, 1) = inv.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0) And dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 1) = "" Then
         dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
         dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 1).PasteSpecial
         If inv.Cells(i, 1) = inv.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-2, 0) And dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-2, 2) = "" Then
           dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
           dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-2, 2).PasteSpecial
           If inv.Cells(i, 1) = inv.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-3, 0) And dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-3, 3) = "" Then
              dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
              dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-3, 3).PasteSpecial
              If inv.Cells(i, 1) = inv.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-4, 0) And dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-4, 4) = "" Then
                 dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
                 dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-4, 4).PasteSpecial
                 If inv.Cells(i, 1) = inv.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-5, 0) And dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-5, 5) = "" Then
                    dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
                    dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-5, 5).PasteSpecial
                    If inv.Cells(i, 1) = inv.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-6, 0) And dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-6, 6) = "" Then
                       dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
                       dtl1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-6, 6).PasteSpecial
                    End If
                 End If
              End If
           End If
        End If
     End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your data already sorted by the invoice number?

Comment: Yeah the corresponding invoices are all in a row.

Comment: And there is always one blank line before the change of the invoice nb, as in the figures, right?

Comment: No there's no blank lines, each row directly below is a invocie and detail combination.  I'll post above what I came up with.

Comment: I don't know how to upload what my excel looks like via Jpeg the image upload isn't working well

Comment: Sorry I could not check your last code because I was testing my answer. Please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Ok I will. I'll be able to test it in the morning, thank you I appreciate the time and effort. I'll let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro. It creates a new sheet which groups the invoices by row.
It supposes that the data is in sheets("Invoice") columns A and B, starting at the second row. Please adjust these parameters to your won case.

```
Sub CreateGroupedInvoiceSheet()
    Application.screenUpdating = False
    Dim src As Range: Set src = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A2")
    Dim dest As Range: Set dest = Sheets.Add.Range("A2")
    Dim lastR As Long: lastR = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim curInvoice As Variant

    Do Until src.Row > lastR
        curInvoice = src.Value
        src.Resize(1, 2).Copy dest
        Set dest = dest.Offset(0, 2)
        Set src = src.Offset(1, 0)
        Do While src.Value = curInvoice
            dest.Value = src.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Set dest = dest.Offset(0, 1)
            Set src = src.Offset(1, 0)
         Loop
         Set dest = dest.Offset(1, 0).End(xlToLeft)
    Loop
    Application.screenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It seemed to have worked great man!  Thank you so much.  I'm not overly versed in VBA could you explain what your Do Until and your Do Whiles are doing in your code?  So in the future I might be able to write something like this for myself.

Comment: @MCJNY1992 Glad it helped. Briefly, the `Do Until` loop (which is equivale to `Do While Not`) will span the range until last row. The inner loop will span a subrange elonging the the same invoice, as long as the invoice identifier is the same, move the details on the same row. This continues until a new invoice identifier is found.